# Shell script Program in linux ubuntu to find in difference between two dates

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script with these steps:

```bash
1 echo

2 echo Enter Date 1 ..(Use date format: yyyy/mm/dd)....."

3 read d1

4 echo Enter Date 2 "..... (Use date format: yyyy/mm/dd).....
 
5 read d2

6

7 echo

8 res=$(($(date -d $d2 + %s) $(date -d $d1 + %s)) / 86400) 

9 echo $res days
```

But I want to add the number of Months, Years, hours, and seconds. In my code it only displays the number of days, but I want to add Months, Years, hours and seconds to display like this:

```
'   ' Days
'   ' Months
'   ' Years 
'   ' Hours 
'   ' Seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to do this is to use the date command to first calculate the number of seconds between the two dates:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prompt the user for two dates
echo "Enter Date 1 ..(Use date format: yyyy/mm/dd)....."
read d1
echo "Enter Date 2 ..(Use date format: yyyy/mm/dd)....."
read d2

# Calculate the number of seconds between the two dates
SECONDS=$(($(date -d $d2 +%s) - $(date -d $d1 +%s)))

# Calculate the number of months, years, hours, and seconds between the two dates
MONTHS=$((SECONDS / 2592000))
YEARS=$((SECONDS / 31536000))
HOURS=$((SECONDS / 3600))
SECONDS=$((SECONDS % 60))

# Print the results to the screen
echo "$MONTHS months"
echo "$YEARS years"
echo "$HOURS hours"
echo "$SECONDS seconds"
```

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: how can I fix the seconds it only shows 0 seconds

Comment: Do you need to get the hole period between two dates in seconds or just the remaining in seconds ?